# How to check if given polyhedron is empty

Tags: convex-optimization, linear-programming

Consider a polyhedron specified as following set of equalities and inequalities
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b},\\
&\mathbf{x} \geqslant \mathbf{0}.
\end{aligned}
$$
Are there ways to check if the set is actually empty? Maybe some reasonable heuristics are available? Finally, if the polyhedron is not empty, how do I find a point with the smallest number of non-zero componens?

For my particular problem the number of columns in A is signifinactly larger than the number of rows.

Comment: Any reason you have to use that "inequality symbol"?

Comment: I would associate that symbol with cardinality and injective functions, not necessarily an "inequality" symbol of the kind you're using here... $\geq$ or $\geqslant$

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/669085/what-does-curly-curved-less-than-sign-succcurlyeq-mean

Comment: More rows than columns? You have an overdetermined set of linear equations then. The first thing you should do is see if you can even solve the equations.

Comment: Sorry for confusion, the system is underdetermined and has full row rank.

Comment: It's still not clear what is "special" about this question. This is just the constraint set for a linear program in standard form. Methods for determining its feasibility are well known.

Comment: There was nothing special. I just didn't know that. Now i do.

Comment: Gotcha. I'll offer an answer to the second part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, determining a solution with the smallest number of non-zeros is intractable. It can be expressed as the following binary linear program:
\begin{array}{ll}
\text{minimize}_{x,y}   & \sum_i y_i \\
\text{subject to} & A x = b \\
                  & 0 \leq x \leq M y \\
                  & y \in \{0,1\}^n
\end{array}
where $M$ is a large number known to bound the largest feasible values of $x$. A common heuristic is to solve
\begin{array}{ll}
\text{minimize}_{x,y}   & \sum_i x_i \\
\text{subject to} & A x = b \\
                  & x \geq 0 \\
\end{array}
This will tend to produce a solution with many zero entries, but without a guarantee that it is truly the minimum. There are a variety of other heuristics one can employ. For instance, some people employ iterative reweighting schemes, which involve solving a sequence of problems of the form
\begin{array}{ll}
\text{minimize}_{x,y}   & \sum_i d_i^{(k)} x_i \\
\text{subject to} & A x = b \\
                  & x \geq 0 \\
\end{array}
The first iteration uses $d_i^{(1)}\equiv 1$;  i.e., the same problem above. This produces a solution $x^{(1)}$. For each subsequent iteration, you choose
$$d^{(k+1)}_i = 1 / (x_i^{(k)} + \epsilon)$$
where $\epsilon$ is small. This puts extra weight on small values of $x$ to drive more of them to zero.

Another approach is a *homotopy method*, for instance
\begin{array}{ll}
\text{minimize}_{x,y}   & \sum_i x_i^{p_k} \\
\text{subject to} & A x = b \\
                  & x \geq 0 \\
\end{array}
For $k=1$, you choose $p_1=1$; i.e., the original linear program. Then you solve a sequence of problems with $p_k\rightarrow 0$ using the previous solution as an initial point for the next. For $p_k<1$, this is non-convex, so there is no guarantee that the solution is global. I personally like iterative reweighting better.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved with use of an auxillary problem of the form
$$
\operatorname{minimize} p = \sum_i y_i\\
\operatorname{s.t.} \mathbf{Ax} + \mathbf{Ey} = \mathbf{b}\\
\mathbf{x} \geqslant 0\\
\mathbf{y} \geqslant 0.
$$
Assuming $\mathbf{b} \geqslant 0$ (can be achieved by multiplying rows of $\mathbf{Ax}=\mathbf{b}$ by $\operatorname{sgn} \mathbf{b}$), the basic feasible solution for this problem is $\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0}, \mathbf{y} = \mathbf{b}$. If the optimum solution to the auxillary problem is $p = 0$, than $\mathbf{x}$ is a feasible point for original problem, otherwise there's no such point.