# Properties of a proper cone

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $K$ be a proper cone. I need to prove following properties:

1. if $x \preceq_K y$ and $u \preceq_K v$, then $x+u \preceq_K y+v$
2. if $x \preceq_K y$ and $y \preceq_K z$, then $x \preceq_K z$
3. if $x \preceq_K y$ and $\alpha \geq 0$, then $\alpha x \preceq_K \alpha y$
4. $x \preceq_K x$

I can comprehend all of these in a graphical way as elements being ordered component-wise. But that does not qualify as a proof. What is the proper way of proving such properties?

Comment: What do you mean by the symbol with subscript $K$?

Comment: That is a partial ordering induced by the proper convex cone, which is defining generalized inequalities on $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: I might be wrong, but it seems like these four properties follow just by the definition of a cone. For example, if $x-y\in K$ and $y-z\in K$, then $x-y+y-z=x-z\in K$.

Comment: Yes, I think you are correct. Due to $x \preceq_K  y \Leftrightarrow x -y\in K$ and $\theta_1\cdot x + \theta_2 \cdot y \in K$ we may write $x-y+y-z=x-z \in K \Leftrightarrow x \preceq_K z$. If you post your description as an answer, I would not mind accepting it as the right answer.

Comment: Nahh it's fine, glad I can help (:

Comment: @CheeHan, regarding the notation: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/669085/what-does-curly-curved-less-than-sign-succcurlyeq-mean/669115#669115

Comment: Number 4 is particularly trivial, since it is equivalent to $0\in\mathcal{K}$.