# Second-order cone constraints

Tags: convex-optimization, constraints, convex-cone

If we have a system of constraints given by,

$$Ax \preceq_K b$$

where $K$ is a second-order cone, would this simply be the same as requiring that:

$$\|Ax\|_2 \leq b$$

where $\|\cdot\|_2$ is the $2$-norm. Or is there something deeper that I'm missing?

EDIT: Having thought about it a bit more, if we define a second-order cone to be $Q^n=\{(u_0,u_1) \in R \times R^{n-1}|u_0 \geq \|u_1\|_2\}$, would the constraint given by,
$$Ax \preceq_{Q^n} b$$
imply that we require
$$b_0-(Ax)_0 \geq \|b_1-(Ax)_1\|_2$$

Comment: Have you checked the definition of $\preceq_K$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/669085/what-does-curly-curved-less-than-sign-succcurlyeq-mean/

Comment: Your edit is close to being correct, but note that the $K$ means something---it denotes the cone of interest. So what you really want here is $Ax \preceq_{Q^n} b$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think they're the same. $Ax \preceq_K b \iff Ax - b \preceq_K 0 \iff -(Ax-b) \in K$. So if $K$ were the positive orthant, then we'd have the standard affine constraint $Ax - b \leq 0$.

A second-order (Lorentz) cone is defined by $L_n := \{(x,t): \|x\|_2 \leq t, t\geq 0, x \in \mathbb{R}^n \}$, so $\tilde{x} = (x,t) \in L_n \iff \tilde{x} \succeq_{L_n} 0$, i.e., $\|x\|_2 \leq t$. Basically, you need to specify the "$t$" in $b-Ax \succeq_{L_n} 0$ (or it seems to be somehow implicitly defined as the last element?).

Note that 
$
\begin{bmatrix}
Ax \\ b
\end{bmatrix} \succeq_{L_n} 0 \iff \|Ax\|_2 \leq b
$ where $b\in \mathbb{R}$. Also note that if we define $y = Ax$, then $\|y\|_2 \leq b$ and $\|-y\|_2 \leq b$, so we can see that for a "proper" cone, we need the $b$ to scale too, otherwise $y$ and $-y$ are both in the cone.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm still a little confused. However, I've edited my above post which hopefully is correct this time

Comment: I think your latest edit is correct (if the $(\cdot)_0$ is a scalar and the $(\cdot)_1$ is a vector)

Comment: Great, thanks jjjjjj. Yup, $(\cdot)_0$ is a scalar and $(\cdot)_1$ is a vector