# What does the symbol "$\succeq$" mean? Is it equivalent to $"\ge"$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation

> We first introduce non-negative Lagrangian multipliers $\lambda = \{\lambda_k\} \succeq 0$ and $\beta = \{\beta_k\} \succeq 0$ associated with the rate constraint $(15\mathrm d)$, $\nu = \{\nu_k\} \succeq 0$ associated with the ernergy causality constraints $(15\mathrm e)$ and $(15\mathrm f)$. In addition, non-negative Lagrangian multipliers $\mu \ge 0$ and $\xi \ge 0$ are associated with  the total time constraint $(15\mathrm b)$ and total energy constraint at $\mathrm{HRN}$ $(15\mathrm c)$. Then the Lagrangian of Problem $(\mathrm{P1'})$ is given $\cdots$

Taken from [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.09859.pdf#page=4).

I found a symbol that I am not familiar with. Does anyone know the symbol $\succeq$?

Comment: $\preceq$ is generally used to denote an arbitrary partial order or total order where the specific order being referred to is explicitly stated in the context.

Comment: @Creator "Being majorized by" is an example of a partial order.  The specific example that the OP is looking at however does not appear to have anything to do with that partial order specifically, but rather another one.

Comment: They are writing down the [Lagrange dual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duality_(optimization)#The_strong_Lagrangian_principle:_Lagrange_duality) problem. The symbol $\succcurlyeq$ just means $\geq0$ (for each $k$). See in the dual problem how the dual variables corresponding to inequalities (that 15d are inequality constrains) are imposed the non-negativity condition.

Comment: The $\{\lambda_k\}$ notation is a little unusual.

Comment: Instead of an image of a small portion, a [link to the full paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.09859.pdf#page=4) gives more information.

Comment: Just to let you know, in Approximation theory, $x \succeq y$ means that there exists a constant $C>0$ independent in $x$, $y$ and some "other parameters" of the context such that $x\geq Cy$

Comment: [Here's](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/669085/what-does-curly-curved-less-than-sign-succcurlyeq-mean/669115) the same question answered elsewhere. Cheers!

Comment: @copper.hat In my experience, it is not that unusual. That said, I personally think it is bad notation.