# Proof of inequality in positive semidefinite matrix

Tags: matrices, inequality, positive-semidefinite

> Let $X \in \Bbb R^{n \times p}$ and $A \in \Bbb R^{k \times p}$, where $k<p$ and $\mbox{rank} (A)=k$, be arbitrary matrices. Prove that $$\left( X^T X \right)^{-1} \geq \left( X^T X \right)^{-1}A^T \left( A \left( X^T X \right)^{-1} A^T \right)^{-1} A \left( X^T X \right)^{-1}.$$ Assume that $X^T X$ and $A \left(X^T X \right)^{-1}A^T$ are invertible.

---

My idea is to use orthogonal diagonalization on both sides since both sides are positive semidefinite matrices. However, I still have no idea what to do next.

Comment: What does $\geq$ denote?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo For square matrices $A,B$, $A \geq B$ if $A-B$ is positive semidefinite.

Comment: Why not use $\succeq$ (`\succeq`)?

Comment: Sorry but I'm not familiar with that notation. What does $\succeq$ mean?

Comment: What you wrote.  To distinguish from entrywise $\geq$

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/669115/339790)

Answer (score 0):

Let $B=\sqrt{(X^TX)^{-1}}A^T$, then we only need to show $I\succeq B(B^TB)^{-1}B^T$. Use singular value decomposition, $B=UDV$ and {$s_i$} are the singular values, then $(B^TB)^{-1}=V^Tdiag\{s_1^{-2},\cdots,s_k^{-2},0,\cdots,0\}V$, so RHS=$Udiag\{1,\cdots,1,0,\cdots,0\}U^T\preceq I$.