# Meaning of $\alpha I \preceq \nabla ^2 F$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, convex-optimization, hessian-matrix

I learned that the notation $\alpha I \preceq \nabla ^2 F $ means that $\langle \alpha x, x\rangle \leq \langle \nabla^2 F x, x\rangle$.

1. What is this called? I know that $\nabla^2 F \succeq 0$ is means that $F$ is positive semidefinite. What would we call $\alpha I \preceq \nabla ^2 F $ which I guess is a weaker version?
2. Is this related to $\nabla F$ being Lipschitz continuous? It roughly looks like an upper/lower bound on $\nabla \cdot \nabla F$, but I don't understand the vector case where we work with inner products.
3. I saw in a paper that $\alpha I \preceq \nabla ^2 F $ implied that $\langle \nabla F(x) - \nabla F(y) , \; x-y \rangle \geq \alpha \|x-y\|^2_2$. I can see why $\langle \nabla^2 F(x-y) ,  \; x-y \rangle \geq \alpha \|x-y\|^2_2$ from the definition, but I don't know why this would apply to $\nabla F(x) - \nabla F(y)$ on the left hand side.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loewner_order

Comment: Usually with a partial order like that, $A\succeq B$ means $A-B\succeq 0.$

Comment: For 3, note that for a differentiable $f$, you can show that $f$ is convex **iff** $f$ is monotone.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/669085/339790)

Comment: It means that the function is strictly convex and can be bounded below by a convex paraboloid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For #3:

Fix $x$ and $y$. Define $g(t) = F(y+t(x-y))$. Then $g'(t) = \langle \nabla F(y+t(x-y)), x-y\rangle$ and $g''(t) = \langle (\nabla^2 F(y+t(x-y))) x-y, x-y \rangle$.

Then $$\langle \nabla F(x) - \nabla F(y), x-y\rangle
= g'(1)-g'(0).$$
By the mean value theorem, there exists some $c \in [0, 1]$ such that the above equals
$$g''(c) = \langle (\nabla^2 F(y+t(x-y))) (x-y), x-y \rangle \ge \alpha \|x-y\|^2$$
where the last bound follows from the definition of $\alpha I \preceq \nabla^2 F$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I still have a question about it. In the last line, I'd expect that we use something like $\langle \nabla^2 F (x-y) , x-y\rangle \geq \alpha \|x-y\|^2$. Why does the inequality work with the $y+t(x-y)$?

Comment: and do you mean $\nabla^2F(y+t(x-y))(x-y)$ rather than $\nabla^2F(y+t(x-y))x-y$?

Comment: @900edges Thanks, I have fixed my typo. In the first sentence of your question, you wrote $\langle \alpha x, x \rangle \le \langle \nabla^2 F x, x \rangle$, but it is ambiguous where the Hessian is evaluated. I am assuming that the inequality holds for any place the Hessian is evaluated, that is $\langle \alpha x, x \rangle \le \langle \nabla^2 F(u) x, x \rangle$ for all $x$ and $u$. Having a global bound on the Hessian is a common assumption for these kind of results.